# Python can't install with pyenv in mac

Tags: python, macos

`$ brew install pyenv-virtualenv`

and append the following to .bash_profile.

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

`$ source ~/.bash_profile`

and install python.

`$ pyenv install 2.7.11`

Then the error occured.

`zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`

How to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is following command.

`$ xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1):

Tried above solution but found this in my google research fixing my issue installing Python 3.6.7 with pyenv
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1219

```
$ sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Hopes that helps!